# GWT development mode with FireFox

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-platform

I am developing a GWT application using GWT, SmartGWT and GWTP. At the beginning I run the development mode with IE 8 and it works fine. But when I run the dev mode with FF, some Click Events are not response. I don't know if this happens because I use SmartGWT or GWTP. Could anyone tell me what's happening? Thanks.

---

Here is the code for one the not responding ClickEvent on the SmartGWT listgrid:

```
navigationListGrid.addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Record record = event.getRecord();
        PlaceRequest myRequest = new PlaceRequest(record.getAttributeAsString("place"));
        placeManager.revealPlace(myRequest);
    }
});
```

Comment: usually GWT avoids browser quirks. Can you show us some code what the buttons do when clicked? Maybe it´s an security issue.

Comment: @dan But why it works fine on IE?

Comment: I meant that Firefox may have higher security settings, but I dont get an idea why it doesnt work, sorry.

Comment: I used to mix Gwt and Smartgwt and got some nasty events problem (it was with a TreeGrid) and it was not always the same thing. I switched to full Smartgwt and since didn't meet anymore these problems.

Comment: What version of Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox releases updates rapidly, and their plugin design means that the GWT Dev Mode plugin must be modified every time a new release is made, the recompiled, and re-released. Long before an official release is made, Alan Leung on the GWT team posts a link to the next version. I've been using FF9 for some time, with the plugin provided on this post https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/jZ02n9v9-H4/87XWXmjcCoAJ. If you still have problems with that plugin and FF9, add a comment on that thread with a code sample to reproduce it so the plugin bug can be investigated before the official version is released.

Chrome is actually significantly slower than most other browsers in Dev mode (compiled javascript will probably be faster in Chrome though) and there are bugs that the team is unable to keep up with http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5778#c65 - the recomendation from project member Thomas Broyer is to use firefox instead.

If you also have problems with Firefox with compiled javascript, that may suggest a bug with GWT, but in production mode, GWT should be fully compatible with the latest Firefox versions.

Comment: So the GWT can be used with FF9. But not with FF7?

Comment: I upgraded with FF7,8,9, following the posts on the google group by Alan - I used this search to find more plugins https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-web-toolkit/alan$20firefox$20plugin - FF7, for example, is in this thread https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/9_KDrtd9MdA/aaftJsg9CoQJ

Answer (score 1):

GWT is not compatible with all Firefox Versions. Currently, it can only run on Firefox prior to **Firefox 6**!

Comment: Thanks. Is it just not compatible for the dev mode?

Comment: It's not compatible with any mode! Actually the best Browser with GWT is Chrome because Google built both so the best compatibility

Comment: I think it may work on Firefox 6.0, but surely it won't run on FF 7 or FF 8